# Debugging Code-Signing errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, codesign

How can one debug errors related to code-signing and missing certificates?  Can I do the process from command line?

In XCode under 'Organizer > Provisioning Profiles', I get 'A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain'.  How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Given the problem is common, it may help to have a laundry list of possibilities of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible problems:

1. The certificates have expired
2. The certificates have been renewed without updating the application provisions
3. The private/public keys are missing from keychain.  They should have been generated when you created the certificate request.
4. The certificates and public/private keys are stored in a keychain other than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions with no luck--I was able to solve it by right-clicking on my System keychain (in Keychain Access), and making it the default keychain. Prior to this, my default was set to "Login."